# Spring maven dependencies not copied in the WEB-INF/lib folder

Tags: spring, gwt, maven

I have a working GWT-App Engine web project which works before I added the Spring dependency in the POM. Now when I run the application, this error is thrown (and ultimately App engine won't load):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

I think the problem is that the Spring jars are not copied to the WEB-INF/lib folders as I can't see those in that folder.

Any ideas how Spring jars will be copied to that folder?

**Update:**

[Here's the complete POM.xml](http://pastebin.com/86qFkhMx)

Comment: How are you running the web app - from IDE or creating a war and deploying manually?

Comment: Without your POM text it's just guessing. Paste the POM of your WAR (at least `dependencies` and `build` sections) and we'll see what's going on there.

Comment: Please don't post links to pastebin and the likes - they will die. Instead, paste the contents of your pom here (strip irrelevant parts though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<packaging>war</packaging>`. Currently Maven doesn't copy any dependencies artifacts into `WEB-INF/lib` because that's a default behaviour of `jar` packaging you used so far for this artifact.

Comment: Yes, I added it. However I am getting this weird error: Description Resource Path Location Type The App Engine SDK 'C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.5.0\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.0.jar' on the project's build path is not valid (SDK location 'C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.5.0\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.0.jar' is not a directory) MyGwtApp  Unknown Google App Engine Problem

Comment: Should I manually  delete 'appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.0.jar' in this case?

Comment: In general, you should switch to Maven-managed dependencies by adding all used artifacts to `dependencies` section of your POMs (as you already did with GWT). It smells like some libs still sit inside `WEB-INF/lib` directory. Where do you have this problem? In Eclipse or while building the app by Maven?

Comment: @xybrek - You are probably getting that in Eclipse. Make sure that the GAE classpath container (usually called "App Engine SDK") is higher than the Maven classpath container (usually called "Maven Dependencies"). Fix this in project properties, "Java Build Path", "Order and Export"

Comment: @PaulGrime I realized that the Spring jars are still not copied in the WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: Try with command line and `mvn clean package`, quit Eclipse first (or disable autobuild). Still nothing?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

after

```
<groupId>mygwtapp</groupId>
<artifactId>mygwtapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Comment: Yes, I added it. However I am getting this weird error: Description Resource Path Location Type The App Engine SDK 'C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.5.0\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.0.jar' on the project's build path is not valid (SDK location 'C:\Users\admin\.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.5.0\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.5.0.jar' is not a directory) MyGwtApp  Unknown Google App Engine Problem

Comment: Do you have some dependencies with groupId com.google.appengine?

Comment: Not at all, based on the POM.xml I have posted. There is one but it's commented. I actually tried putting that however I failed to download jars.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Eclipse IDE with m2eclipse plugin

Answer (score 1):

Add them as Maven dependencies to your war and make sure their scope is not "provided".